# How register ticket for some event from Eventbrite API

Tags: eventbrite

I was looking at eventbrite api and i just wondering is there a way i can register a new ticket for some event knowing it's id?

Answer (score 1):

Eventbrite incorporates a [web-based workflow](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/workflows/) to carry out that task.

Providing a link to your event page should allow the user to complete their registration on their own.  You can also manually add an attendee using Eventbrite's web-based event administration tools.

Due to security and privacy considerations, it is not likely that this feature will become available as an API method.